# Is it bad practice to make the title of the page a link?

Tags: web, hyperlinks, title, seo

For example, on ux.stackexchange.com the question is a link to the current page. (for SEO purpose I suppose).

But in order to select (and copy) a line of text, I usually triple click, which is not possible on links.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's bad practice to make a title a link, though it all depends on your use case.

For example, the title of YouTube videos aren't links.

For me personally, I drag to select or if on mobile, long press and select "copy link text".